# How many directories can be nested?

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, mkdir

I'm curious, how many folders can be nested, and why? Is there a limit?

What I mean by nested is when folders are in this structure:

```
folder
 |_ folder
     |_ folder
         |_ folder
             |_ ...
```

Not like this:

```
folder
 |_ folder
 |_ folder
 |_ folder
 |_ ...
```

If there is a limit, is it set by the operating system, or by the file system?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The limit will be the number of `inode`s on your partition since directories, like regular files, take an inode each.

Nothing would stop you from creating a directory inside a directory inside another directory and so on until you run out of `inode`s.

Note that the shell's command line does have a maximum length which can cause issues with really long paths, but it would still be possible to `cd` progressively towards the target file.

Comment: Indeed, by experiment this is what `mkdir -p` does and it allows to exceed `MAX_PATH`. Such files can't be opened by their canonical path, but one can create them without problems.

Comment: Awesome answer. Any external references?

Comment: It's pretty logical, actually. A relative path starts at the current working directory, an inode. Inodes are not arranged hierarchically: there is no difference in this respect between a directory that is linked deep in the name hierachy and the file system's root directory.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The POSIX (and Linux) API defines a maximum PATH_MAX (4096 on Linux), that is much shorter than the maximum length of the command line. And while we are nitpicking: the maximum command line is not really a shell restriction. The limit is imposed by the argument vector length to the `execve` system call, and so applies to any program.

Comment: @JohanMyréen:  Those are good observations but my point was that it would still be accessible relatively, no matter how deep it goes.

Comment: How do I find the number of `inode`s I have? Or, how can I find the number of possible nested directories?

Comment: @JohanMyréen What about built-ins? Those don't require `execve`.

Comment: @Arin Try `df -i`.

Comment: @phk There is no restriction on command line length for built-ins. Other limits, like PATH_MAX may apply, though.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thanks. I changed the command to `df -ih .` so it shows only current partition.

Comment: In the second `folder` example I posted, is that also limited by the number of `inode`s? And also, what happens when it runs out of `inode`s?

Comment: No, that's a different question.  The size of directory (file) has limitations based on the filesystem used.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/466596/5207302 explains that pretty well.  Do note that having big directories can yield to serious performance issues for operations as simple as opening a file from that directory.

Comment: @Arin When you run out of inodes you get a "File system full" error, just like when you run out of disk space.

Comment: @Arin The inode limit applies to the total number of files and directories in a filesystem. How they're organized is irrelevant.